# Does anyone know how to invoke the Zone FIll option in QCC for R

Tags: r, charts, syntax, qcc

There is an option in QCC to fill the zones with colors. I have tried calling this option in my code but I don't think I understand how to call it or provide the arguments correctly and I am stuck, stuck, stuck.  Picture below shows zones filled and not filled and the documented examples. Somewhere I'm missing either the proper syntax for invoking the fill or I'm missing something not so obvious to me.

I have tried the following variations from the documentation without success:

```
qcc.options("zones")$fill
```

I put the fill = TRUE in the code that plots my chart as the example shows. It doesn't throw an error but  it doesn't do the fill.

```
cht <- qcc(v, type="xbar.one", plot = "FALSE" , labels = xticks )
plot(cht, restore.par =FALSE, fill= TRUE, title = "", xlab = "", ylab = "moisture %", axes.las = 2, add.stat = FALSE )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if qcc has that feature.  One work around is to use the `rect()` function from the base graphics package.

```
library(qcc)

#generate some random data
v <- rnorm(30, 74, .5)

#create the chart object
cht <- qcc(v, type="xbar.one", plot = "FALSE"  )

#plot
plot(cht, restore.par =FALSE, fill= TRUE, title = "", xlab = "", ylab = "moisture %", axes.las = 2, add.stat = FALSE )

#now add the box as an extra feature.  Use the grey function to set the color.
#access the limits stored in the cht object.
rect(0, cht$limits[2], length(cht$statistics)+1, cht$limits[1], col=grey(0.8, .3))
```

[image]

Comment: @jamesTurner, Did this answer your question or did you have another one related to qcc?  From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467150/improving-qcc-statistics-calculations-in-r/35468410?noredirect=1#comment136119816_35468410

Comment: Yes this is a good work-around. One question: the I don't understand the color argument, color = grey(0.8, .3). This is new to me. How would I change the fill color? Is there a reference I could look up to understand color arguments in this context?

Comment: The first term is the level 0 to 1 where  0 is black and 1 is white.  The second term is  the alpha, where 0 is transparent and 1 is opaque.  If you want another color then the `rgb()` function will work.  See `?rgb` for more help.

Comment: This option does exist in qcc. But I don't see any examples in the documentation that show how to do it. If you look here:  https://luca-scr.github.io/qcc/reference/qcc.html you can see how the 3 zones are shaded nicely.

Comment: I believe that website is out of date.  If you look at the vignette that is installed with the package, none of the examples have a shaded region.  I am afraid if you want to shade the plot you will need a work around like above.

Comment: okay. Thanks. I just saw that nicely shaded chart in the package docs and thought it looked so elegant.  Thanks again.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. I have been tinkering with the charts using the rect() that you showed me, using the qcc object parameters to create the different zones and it looks great. Thank you so much for that gentle push. I'm now trying to figure out if I can change the plotted point size but I have come up empty.  I tried to use size=# when defining the object but that didn't work. I also tried it in the when doing the plot. That also did not bear fruit.  I can change the colors of the  violating run and  beyond limits points just not the size of all the points.